# How to fix Resolving dependencies... Error when using flutter run?

Tags: dart, flutter

when I used Flutter run in my terminal in error is coming. but app is working. my app is very slow.

> Note: C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\connectivity-0.4.2\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\connectivity\ConnectivityPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecate
>       d API.
>       Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add  this to the release mode android manifest

Comment: Can you explain how to add it?

Answer (score 0):

It is a warning not an error, this is evident by the fact your code is executing when you run it. And it's related to the structure of your plugin and have nothing to do with your code.